# How stressful is work of quants?

Tags: stress, general

I would like to know how stressful this work can be and where the stress could come from. How to avoid it? Does it really depend on the company you are working? Is there a way to know in advance if work in a particular company is stressful or not?

Comment: i.e. how long is a piece of string? :D ... It depends on the country, boss, team, company, salary, market, weather, etc. It would be interesting to see people commenting on their particular situation but I doubt they will be willing to give too much information.

Comment: @Terco, why do you think people will not be willing to give information? Of course, I do not expect to get names of companies, bosses names and so on. I just want to know how is it to work in finance (because I only have experience of work in science).

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://quant.stackexchange.com/faq): *The Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange is intended for professionals and academics involved in securities valuations, risk modeling, and other topics related to quant modeling or trading. Basically, if you aren't earning a living at this, it's probably off topic.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more stressful than the work of a tenured professor but less stressful than the work of a postdoc.